# NodeJS JSON file's properties are resetting to undefined after editing a property

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, file, discord.js

When I'm editing a JSON file, the other properties are gone / undefined, I'm  using Nodejs v14 on a raspberry pi 4.

Initial JSON content :

```
{
  "808327471816245248": {
    "LeaveMessage":"test",
    "WelcomeChannel": "814906779402109018"
  },
}
```

My code to edit a property :

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const config = require("../../../serverconfig.json");
config[guild].LeaveMessage = "test1";
      fs.writeFileSync(
            client.config.path,
            JSON.stringify(config, null, 2)
        );
```

Resulting JSON content :

```
{
  "808327471816245248": {
    "LeaveMessage":"test1",
  },
}
```

Does anyone has an idea why this happens ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `writeFileSync()` method overwrites everything that is in the JSON file already, which is why the other property is being deleted. To get around this you can first read from the file using `readFileSync`, parse the JSON into a JavaScript object and then edit the properties of this object before writing it to the file.

For example:

```js
const fs = require("fs");

let rawData = fs.readFileSync(PATH_TO_FILE);
let obj = JSON.parse(rawData);

obj[guild].LeaveMessage = "test1";

let newData = JSON.stringify(obj);
fs.writeFileSync(PATH_TO_FILE, newData);
```